# Using extended precision in numpy prod

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I have a 2d numpy array `x` of size `11 x 20000`. The rows mostly consists of small decimal values (with some occasional `0`s). I want to take the product of only the non-zero values. I can easily do this by using `numpy.prod`:

```
y = numpy.prod(x, axis = 1, where = arr > 0)
```

`y` has only `11` elements that is the product of non-zero elements of `x`'s rows. But, after printing the contents of `y`, I find out that in some cases every element of `y` is becoming `0`. I suppose it's a precision issue as `y`'s value in becoming less that some threshold that numpy can't represent. So use the highest precision, I change the `np.prod` as follows:

```
y = np.prod(x, axis = 1, where = arr > 0, dtype = np.longdouble)
```

But the result is the same. I then print out the implementation of `np.longdouble`:

```
print(np.finfo(np.longoduble))
>>> Machine parameters for float64
---------------------------------------------------------------
precision =  15   resolution = 1.0000000000000001e-15
machep =    -52   eps =        2.2204460492503131e-16
negep =     -53   epsneg =     1.1102230246251565e-16
minexp =  -1022   tiny =       2.2250738585072014e-308
maxexp =   1024   max =        1.7976931348623157e+308
nexp =       11   min =        -max
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

So the least value numpy can represent on my machine is `e-308`. But on my friend's computer the same command prints:

[image]

Now I suppose I do not have the necessary hardware support for extended precision on my machine. But when I run the following `C++` code on my machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << numeric_limits<long double>::min() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.3621e-4932
```

So, clearly I have hardware support to access much lower values than `e-308`. My question is, how can I use `float128` implementation for `np.longdouble` on my machine?

Additional information:

```
numpy version: 1.18.1
python version: 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Use `dtype = np.float128` explicitly instead in `np.prod`?

Comment: @amzon-ex, Using that throws an error: ``AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float128'``

Comment: It seems like `np.longdouble` defaults to float64 on Windows machines. On a Linux machine, it is supposed to yield float128.

Comment: It seems you're right @amzon-ex. My friend was using Ubuntu. But why doesn't windows machine defaults to float128 on a 64 bit machine? And is there any way to activate this functionality?